# PHPMailer error de conexión al servidor

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estoy haciendo pruebas con `PHPMAILER` en `XAMPP` y me funciona perfectamente.  Al pasar el código al host del cliente me arroja el siguiente error:

> Failed to connect to server: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (10013) 2018-11-01 21:25:47  SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

La verdad no se por que no me funciona
Este es el código que estoy utilizando

```
require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
require("PHPMailer/class.smtp.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer;//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail->isSMTP();//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com";
$mail->Password = "xxxxxx";
$mail->setFrom('xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress('xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com', 'John Doe');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->Body = "HOLA. COMO ESTAS";
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
  }
}

function save_mail($mail)
{
    $path = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}[Gmail]/Sent Mail";
    $imapStream = imap_open($path, $mail->Username, $mail->Password);
    $result = imap_append($imapStream, $path, $mail->getSentMIMEMessage());
    imap_close($imapStream);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haz probado a cambiar el puerto y el protocolo? Serían estas dos líneas:

```
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```